# Tortoise ORM Pydantic is generating the wrong required fields

Tags: python, orm, pydantic

I have the following Tortoise model defined:

```
class Org(SuperModel):
    id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=128)
    description = fields.TextField(max_length=2048, null = True)
    users = fields.ManyToManyField('models.User', related_name='org', through='org_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class PydanticMeta:
        exclude = ["id"]
```

When I generate a pydantic schema from this I get the following:

```
{
    "additionalProperties":false,
    "properties":{
        "name":{
            "maxLength":128,
            "title":"Name",
            "type":"string"
        },
        "description":{
            "anyOf":[
                {
                  "type":"string"
                },
                {
                    "type":"null"
                }
            ],
            "nullable":true,
            "title":"Description"
        }
    },
    "required":[
        "name",
        "description"
    ],
    "title":"Org",
    "type":"object"
}
```

What I can't work out is why are name AND description required in the pedantic schema? Surely setting null = True on description should make it not required.